# Piecewise-linear (or otherwise monotonic) interpolation as a matrix problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, interpolation

**Background**: I'm hoping to find (or write) an algorithm to piecewise linear-interpolate large sets of unevenly sampled functions (10s of thousands of arrays of a thousand or so $x$ and $y$ pairs, where each array $x_i$ are not the same).  [Iterating over each $y_i(x_i)$ and creating interpolants is expensive (*see this stackoverflow question for more info*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37393832/vectorized-sum-of-interpolated-values-over-many-arrays).  Because polynomial interpolation can be formulated as a (Vandermond) matrix problem it can be sped up significantly by attacking it as a single 3D matrix.

**Question**: Is there any way to formulate *piecewise* interpolation as a similar matrix problem, so that it can be sped up?  Alternatively, is there a different set of basis-functions (besides polynomials) which would be guaranteed to be monotonic between each pair of points, which could be linearized?